# inner join mysql PHP, how to join up on relational column

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I have two tables,

'users' and 'permissions'

users has a column: 'permissions' of type *int*.

permissions has a column: 'id' of type *int (AI)*

I want to select a user and return the value of the permissions column where the id = the same as the users id.

I have tried this:

```
$queryString = "
    SELECT 
        u.*, 
        p.value
    FROM 
        users u,
        permissions p
    WHERE 
        username = '$username' AND
        password = '" . md5( $password ) . "'
    INNER JOIN 
        user u on p.id = u.permissions
";
```

So instead of returning a user with:

> id = 1, username = "bob", permissions = 3

it would say

> permissions = "admin"

because that's the value in the permissions table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$queryString = "
    SELECT 
        u.*, 
        p.value
    FROM 
        users u INNER JOIN 
        permissions p ON
        p.id = u.permissions
    WHERE 
        u.username = '$username' AND
        u.password = '" . md5( $password ) . "'

";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result:

```
SELECT  
    p.value
FROM 
    permissions p
INNER JOIN 
    users u on p.id = u.permissions
WHERE 
    username = '$username' AND
    password = '" . md5( $password ) . "'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
 $queryString = "SELECT u.*, p.value
    FROM users AS u
    INNER JOIN permissions AS p ON u.permissions = p.id
    WHERE 
       u.username = '$username' AND
       u.password = '" . md5( $password ) . "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*, p.value from users u, permissions p 
where
p.id=u.permissions
and
u.username='$username'
and
u.password='" . md5( $password ) . "'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the structure of your two tables?

I guess your query should look like, I am assuming `p.value` contains the name of the permission:

```
$queryString = "
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.username,
    p.value AS permissions
FROM 
    users u
INNER JOIN
    permissions p
ON
    p.id = u.permissions
WHERE 
    username = '$username' AND
    password = '" . md5( $password ) . "'
";
```